# Is there a way to change the NETFLIX skip interval Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, media-center

There is a way to change the general skip interval in Media Center.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10762/increase-skip-and-replay-intervals-in-windows-7-media-center/
But it doesn't affect Netflix which stays at 10 seconds no matter what.

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough search of my registry, it doesn't look like the Netflix plugin for Media Center exposes any properties you could change.

Further profiling with Process Monitor showed that the plugin only looks for the user name and auth string, and writes to a local log - no properties or settings file.

I suggest browsing to the [plugin's page](http://www.netflix.com/AppDisplay?id=1277&st=rt&pn=1&lnkctr=apgl-rm-1277) and adding a request/suggestion for this feature.